# Powershell - if test-path true try XYZ else ZZZ isnt working as i want it to

Tags: powershell, loops, error-handling

i'm having issues with the errorhandling of test-path. I bet im using it just wrong, but im here looking for help.

The part where test-path is true works just fine.
But for the part where it's false it doesn't work as i was hoping.

When test-path is false i would like to send an email to me, the mailsettings in general are working fine.
Only the body is making some trouble.

What i'm getting:
A line for every name in my aray, doesnt matter if true or false

What i'm looking for:
Only the lines with the names where test-path is false

I'm trying to replicate the Code in a simple way. :)

Example:

```
$names = 'Adam', 'Beth', 'Cesar'
for ($i = 0; $i -le ($names.length - 1); $i += 1)
{
$path = '\\Server\Test\' + $names[$i] + '\XYZ

if (test-path -path $path)
{try{.... 
#this part is working fine if test-path is 'true'
} else {
$header = "ERROR - Paths are not available"
$body = "The following paths are not available:`n"
for ($i=0; $i -lt $names.count; $i++) {
$body += "`nName: $($name[$i])`n"
$body += "Path: $($path[$i])`n"
}
send-mailmassage ..... #this part is working
```

Lets say only cesar's test-path is false.
What i get is a line for adam, beth and cesar. The skript does its job with adam and beth just fine and sends me an email because cesar isn't available but in the mail i get the name and path of all three.

How do i change that to just write down those where the test-path is false?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you iterate twice over the `$names`, but pay no attention if the path was ok or not. Thus the second for loop will handle all the names again from start to end.

As for a fix, first simplify the code by moving away from `for` loop. A `foreach` will remove any need for loop index maintenance and the code is easier to read. Add another a collection for failed names and send message based on its contents. Like so,

```
$names = 'Adam', 'Beth', 'Cesar'
$notFound = @()
# First work with all the names
foreach($n in $names) {
  if(test-path $n) {...}
  # Make a note about paths not found
  else {$notFound += $n}
}

# If there are elements in the paths not found list,
if($notFound.Count -gt 0) {
  # set up message body
  $body = ...
  # And add all the names to the message
  foreach($n in $notFound) {
    $body += "Name: "+ $n
  }
  send-mailmessage...
}
```

Comment: Hey, thx for the tipp!

I tried to apply the changes to my script and tested it.
I changed the path for cesar to get a 'false' there.
It did send me only one line of missing path, thats the good thing.
But for some reason it did send me the name and path for adam, not cesar.

I'm unsure how to convert the following part to my script
`if(test-path $n) {...}` because i'm using `if(test-path -path $path)` i can't test the name, i need to check the path ... right?

Answer (score 0):

Your code (apart from the bad indentation) shows some serious errors:

1. You construct the path to test with a missing closing quote character on final `\XYZ` part
2. You seem to start off with a `try{..} catch{..}`, but instead do `try{..} else{..}`
3. You're missing final closing curly brackets (probably due to not seeing it as a result of not indenting the code)
4. inside the False part, you start iterating the names array again as if they all failed on the Test-Path cmdlet. Not only that, but in there your variable `$path` is treated as array where it is just a single string. (iow: there **is no** `$path[$i]`)

Try

```
$names  = 'Adam', 'Beth', 'Cesar'

# since it is unclear if your success part will outut anything, 
# use an object designed for adding elements to capture the output for $body
$failed = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
foreach ($name in $names) {
    $path = join-Path -Path '\\Server\Test\' -ChildPath ('{0}\XYZ' -f $name)
    if (Test-Path -Path $path) {
        try { 
            # .... 
        } 
        catch {
            # ....
        }
    }
    else {
        # add whatever you want to appear in the body of your email
        # for demo, a two-line string
        $failed.Add("Name: $name`r`nPath: $path")
    }
}

if ($failed.Count) {
    # you have found paths that do not exist
    $header = "ERROR - Paths are not available"
    $body   = "The following paths are not available:`r`n{0}" -f ($failed -join "`r`n")
    Send-MailMessage # .....
}
```

<sup>If you want to send an HTML formatted email, use `<br />` for line breaks instead of `` "`r`n" ``</sup>

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your feedback! I can asure you your points 1-3 are all handled in the real code. I just missed them in my shortened example. The original skript does ALOT more that just this. At point 4 i'm not quite sure what you mean. Could be a translation related problem on my side. Could you explain that a little bit?

Comment: @Balgor What didn't you understand on item 4? Your code defines `$path` as **string** (`$path = '\\Server\Test\' + $names[$i] + '\XYZ`), not as array. When you do `$path[0]` you will get the first **character** of that string, `$path[$i]` will give you the `$i` indexed character.. If in the false part you start iterating the $names again to build the body for the email, you totally ignore whether they passed the test or not, therefore you list them all where you **only** want to get an email of the failed paths

Comment: ahh ok, that explains why i got, in one of my first variations of this scritp, paths with only one sign ... like adam - "\", beth - "\", cesar - "S", dora - "e", eva - "r" etc ... to be fair that skript is a couple of years old and did its job pretty much flawless. Only thing that botherd me now was, when the server was offline i got a mail for every name every 5min ... because there alot more that just 3-4 names to check it could get really anoying if the server was offline for longer (hundreds of e-mails) i thought i would be a good time for some improvements.

Comment: @Balgor Your post didn't say anything about the server being off-line, but you can start the code with a `if(Test-Connection -ComputerName 'yourServer' -Count 1 -Quiet) { <# the rest of the code #> }`

Comment: @Balgor BTW. if my answer solved your problem, please have a quick read of the [tour] so you can see how to mark a question 'done'. That way, others with similar problems may find the answer as well

Comment: I prefer the test-path, rather than the test-connection in this situation. :)
I Try to apply your answer to my skript as soon as i can, we will see if it solves all my problems.

Comment: @Balgor Why?? You only test the connection to the server once and if that fails you're done. No use testing several paths on a server that is off-line